# How do I make XPlot work on Linux / Mono?

Tags: linux, f#, mono, visual-studio-code, fslab

I have problems using the charting library XPlot for F# on Linux. When I use the "fsharpi"-command to run a standard example script for the candlestick chart, for instance, the script itself runs without any complains but no browser is opened and nothing is shown.

example-script:

```
#load "../packages/FsLab/FsLab.fsx" 
open XPlot.GoogleCharts

let data =
    [
        "Mon", 20, 28, 38, 45
        "Tue", 31, 38, 55, 66
        "Wed", 50, 55, 77, 80
        "Thu", 77, 77, 66, 50
        "Fri", 68, 66, 22, 15        
    ]

Chart.Candlestick data
```

If I run it via:

```
fsharpi "test.fsx"
```

nothing happens, after some time just another line of the command prompt appears, but also no error occurs.
If I run it via:

```
fsharpi
#load "test.fsx";;
```

the following output is shown:

```
[Loading /home/flo/Copy/Mono/FSharp/FinalHashtagVisualizer/packages/FsLab/Shared/Server.fsx
 Loading /home/flo/Copy/Mono/FSharp/FinalHashtagVisualizer/packages/FsLab/Shared/Styles.fsx
 Loading /home/flo/Copy/Mono/FSharp/FinalHashtagVisualizer/packages/FsLab/Text/FsLab.fsx
 Loading /home/flo/Copy/Mono/FSharp/FinalHashtagVisualizer/packages/FsLab/FsLab.fsx
 Loading /home/flo/Copy/Mono/FSharp/FinalHashtagVisualizer/HashtagVisualizer/test.fsx]
namespace FSI_0003.FsLab.Formatters
  type SimpleServer =
    class
      new : unit -> SimpleServer
      member AddPage : page:string -> string
      member
        AddPart : part:(Suave.Http.HttpContext ->
                          Async<Suave.Http.HttpContext option>) -> string
      member Port : Suave.Sockets.Port
    end
  val instance : System.Lazy<SimpleServer>

namespace FSI_0003.FsLab.Formatters
  val private defaultStyles :
    System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string>

namespace FSI_0003.FsLab.Formatters
  val private displayHtml : html:string -> unit

namespace FSI_0003.FSharp.Charting
  type Chart with
    static member
      Line : data:Deedle.Series<'K,#FSharp.Charting.value> * ?Name:string *
             ?Title:string * ?Labels:#seq<string> *
             ?Color:System.Drawing.Color * ?XTitle:string * ?YTitle:string ->
               FSharp.Charting.ChartTypes.GenericChart
               when 'K : equality and 'K :> FSharp.Charting.key
  type Chart with
    static member
      Column : data:Deedle.Series<'K,#FSharp.Charting.value> * ?Name:string *
               ?Title:string * ?Labels:#seq<string> *
               ?Color:System.Drawing.Color * ?XTitle:string * ?YTitle:string ->
                 FSharp.Charting.ChartTypes.GenericChart
                 when 'K : equality and 'K :> FSharp.Charting.key
  type Chart with
    static member
      Pie : data:Deedle.Series<'K,#FSharp.Charting.value> * ?Name:string *
            ?Title:string * ?Labels:#seq<string> * ?Color:System.Drawing.Color *
            ?XTitle:string * ?YTitle:string ->
              FSharp.Charting.ChartTypes.PieChart
              when 'K : equality and 'K :> FSharp.Charting.key
  type Chart with
    static member
      Area : data:Deedle.Series<'K,#FSharp.Charting.value> * ?Name:string *
             ?Title:string * ?Labels:#seq<string> *
             ?Color:System.Drawing.Color * ?XTitle:string * ?YTitle:string ->
               FSharp.Charting.ChartTypes.GenericChart
               when 'K : equality and 'K :> FSharp.Charting.key
  type Chart with
    static member
      Bar : data:Deedle.Series<'K,#FSharp.Charting.value> * ?Name:string *
            ?Title:string * ?Labels:#seq<string> * ?Color:System.Drawing.Color *
            ?XTitle:string * ?YTitle:string ->
              FSharp.Charting.ChartTypes.GenericChart
              when 'K : equality and 'K :> FSharp.Charting.key
namespace FSI_0003.MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra
  val inline toFrame :
    matrix:MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<'a> -> Deedle.Frame<int,int>
      when 'a : (new : unit -> 'a) and 'a : struct and
           'a :> System.IEquatable<'a> and 'a :> System.IFormattable and
           'a :> System.ValueType
  val inline ofFrame :
    frame:Deedle.Frame<'a,'b> -> MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<float>
      when 'a : equality and 'b : equality
  val inline ofFrame :
    frame:Deedle.Frame<'a,'b> -> MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<float>
      when 'a : equality and 'b : equality
  val inline toSeries :
    vector:MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector<'a> -> Deedle.Series<int,'a>
      when 'a : (new : unit -> 'a) and 'a : struct and
           'a :> System.IEquatable<'a> and 'a :> System.IFormattable and
           'a :> System.ValueType
  val inline ofSeries :
    series:Deedle.Series<'a, ^b> ->
      MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector<float>
      when 'a : equality and  ^b : (static member op_Explicit :  ^b -> float)
  val inline ofSeries :
    series:Deedle.Series<'a, ^b> ->
      MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector<float>
      when 'a : equality and  ^b : (static member op_Explicit :  ^b -> float)
namespace FSI_0003.Deedle
  val inline ofMatrix :
    matrix:MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<'a> -> Deedle.Frame<int,int>
      when 'a : (new : unit -> 'a) and 'a : struct and
           'a :> System.IEquatable<'a> and 'a :> System.IFormattable and
           'a :> System.ValueType
  val inline toMatrix :
    frame:Deedle.Frame<'a,'b> -> MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<float>
      when 'a : equality and 'b : equality
  val ofCsvRows :
    data:FSharp.Data.Runtime.CsvFile<'T> -> Deedle.Frame<int,string>
  val inline ofVector :
    vector:MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector<'a> -> Deedle.Series<int,'a>
      when 'a : (new : unit -> 'a) and 'a : struct and
           'a :> System.IEquatable<'a> and 'a :> System.IFormattable and
           'a :> System.ValueType
  val inline toVector :
    series:Deedle.Series<'a, ^b> ->
      MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector<float>
      when 'a : equality and  ^b : (static member op_Explicit :  ^b -> float)

namespace FSI_0003
  val data : (string * int * int * int * int) list
```

I use VS Code and the Ionide-Extension. I installed the FsLab-Package via Fake and generally works well (except for the charting). I created the project via the "new project"-command within VS Code, but I didn't find a way to also run it via a VS Code-command but used the (integrated) console instead. I tried to use NetCore instead of Mono, but didn't find a way to make it work either.
The F# Interactive version I use is 4.1, the latest as far as I know.

I hope my question is now specific enough to meet the community guidelines.

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using, so that we can try to replicate the problem? It's impossible to guess what might be wrong without code to look at: there are too many possibilities.

Comment: I edited my question and made it more specific. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with XPlot, but looking at the docs quickly, don't you need to pipe your chart into `Chart.Show`?

Comment: @Tarmil This works indeed. Thanks a lot! Somehow this detail is missing in the sample scripts. Now I would like to highlight your answer as the solution to my question but this doesn't seem to be possible with comments. So I write the answer myself, I guess? By the way: Is there also a possibility to save the chart to an html-file instead of showing it immedieately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been pointed out in the comments you have to pipe the chart to Chart.Show. Thus the following script should work as intended:

```
#load "../packages/FsLab/FsLab.fsx"
open XPlot.GoogleCharts

let data =
    [
        "Mon", 20, 28, 38, 45
        "Tue", 31, 38, 55, 66
        "Wed", 50, 55, 77, 80
        "Thu", 77, 77, 66, 50
        "Fri", 68, 66, 22, 15        
    ]

Chart.Candlestick data |> Chart.Show
```